# How to test whether a function is positive over the entire range of an interval?

Tags: expression-test

I would like to test whether a function is positive over a given interval. Say I have `f[x_] = -x^3 + x^2 + 7*x` and wanted to know whether it is positive for all `x` in the interval `[0,4]`?

It can easily seen by plotting the function that it is not, but I would like to have a more formal test in the form of "`TrueForAll[f[x] > 0, {x,0,4}]`".

It is probably a trivial problem, but I haven't managed to figure it out myself. So I am grateful for any advice.

Comment: `Reduce[ForAll[x, 0 <= x <= 4 \[Implies] -x^3 + x^2 + 7*x > 0]]`?  (Or `FullSimplify` instead of `Reduce`.)

Comment: @Michael I think we don't need `Implies` here: `Reduce[ForAll[x, x <= 0 <= 4, f[x] > 0]]`

Comment: @Szabolcs I forgot about that form.  I hardly ever use `ForAll`....

Comment: @Szabolcs You have a great solution. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @Pavlo I was waiting for Michael to do it.

Comment: `Min@f[Interval[{0, 4}]] > 0`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To find the intervals for which `f[x]` is positive

```
f[x_] = -x^3 + x^2 + 7*x;

g[x_] = Piecewise[{{f[x], f[x] > 0}}, I];

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -3, 4},
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], Blue}]
```

[image]

```
FunctionDomain[g[x], x]

(*  x < (1/2)*(1 - Sqrt[29]) || 
   0 < x < (1/2)*(1 + Sqrt[29])  *)

% // N

(*  x < -2.19258 || 0. < x < 3.19258  *)
```

EDIT:

Or, more succinctly

```
FunctionDomain[Piecewise[{{1, f[x] > 0}}, I], x]

(*  x < (1/2)*(1 - Sqrt[29]) || 
   0 < x < (1/2)*(1 + Sqrt[29])  *)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for these extremely helpful answers and comments. Bob Hanlon's answer is great because it provides a more comprehensive picture of the function's characteristics, although it does not perform the True/False test I was  looking for. I have found that it can easily be combined with @Michael's and @Szabolcs' approach, however: `xpos = FunctionDomain[Piecewise[{{1, f[x] > 0}}, I], x];` `Reduce[ForAll[x, 0 <= x <= 4, xpos]]`

Answer (score 8):

I like the answers using `Reduce` and `FunctionDomain`. Here's a numerical possibility that uses `Minimize` to find the global minimum on the domain and tests to see if it's positive.

```
f[x_] = -x^3 + x^2 + 7*x;
0 <= First@Minimize[{f[x], 0 <= x <= 4}, x]
(* False *)
```

Alternatively, if needed, you can use `NMinimize`:

```
NMinimize[{f[x], 0 <= x <= 4}, x]
(* {-20., {x -> 4.}} *)
0 <= First@NMinimize[{f[x], 0 <= x <= 4}, x]
(* False *)
```